# Can not get a value of key-value pair using [FromBody]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Data is sent from front-end to back-end. Request body is created like this

```
var stateWithValue = {};

for (const item in self.pricings()) {
    state[item] = self.pricings()[item]["Comment"];
}

var request = {
    generalComment: self.generalComment(),
    stateWithValue: stateWithValue
};
```

Request body looks like this

```
{
generalComment: "test comment",
stateWithValue:
{
  Delaware: "Value1",
  California: "Value2",
  Texas: "Value3"
}
}
```

Number of elements in **stateWithValue** can be different for every request.

In the back-end, data is taken using [FromBody] attribute

```
public WebApiResponseGeneric<EmptyResponse> State([FromBody] StateRequest request)
```

StateRequest.cs

```
public class StateRequest : PublicRequest
{
    public string GlobalComment { get; set; }
    public StateWithValue StateWithValue { get; set; }
}
public class StateWithValue
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In network tab(dev console) payload looks like this

> generalComment: test general comment
> stateWithValue[Delaware]: Value1
> stateWithValue[California]: Value2
> stateWithValue[Texas]: Value3

**The Problem**
In back-end request object, StateWithValue.State StateWithValue.Value are both null.

Comment: For your `stateWithValue` I think you need to use the format `{State: "Delaware", Value: "Value1"}`. I don't often use FromBody with JSON and instead I use form data, in which case you need to index each item in order to get it to bind to a list, e.g. `stateWithValue[0].State = "Delaware", stateWithValue[0].Value = "Value1"`, I'm not sure about JSON though

Comment: @Campbell I can't do that because I do not know how many elements will be in StateWithValue

Comment: I think you will be fine as you are using JSON, this is just how form data works, which is another way to send data from the browser. FYI I added a proper answer to the question, it looks like you will either need to modify the JSON you are sending to the controller, or modify the model that you are binding to in order to handle multiple states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have to post PublicRequest class too. But for your request body json, your class should be

```
public class StateRequest : PublicRequest
{
    public string generalComment{ get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> stateWithValue { get; set; }
}
```

or change

```
public class StateRequest : PublicRequest
{
    public string GlobalComment { get; set; }
    public List<StateWithValue> StateWithValue { get; set; }
}
```

and javascript

```
var stateWithValue = [];

for (const item in self.pricings()) {
    var stateWithValueItem={};
    stateWithValueItem.State =item;
    stateWithValueItem.Value = self.pricings()[item]["Comment"];
   
 stateWithValue.push(stateWithValueItem);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to map the JSON:

```
{
generalComment: "test comment",
stateWithValue:
{
  Delaware: "Value1",
  California: "Value2",
  Texas: "Value3"
}
}
```

You would need to use the following C# model

```
public class StateRequest : PublicRequest
{
    public string GeneralComment { get; set; }
    public StateWithValue StateWithValue { get; set; }
}
public class StateWithValue
{
    public string Dalaware { get; set; }
    public string California { get; set; }
    public string Texas { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to map multiple states then consider using an array instead, something like:

```
{
generalComment: "test comment",
stateWithValue:
[
  State: "Delaware", Value: "Value1",
  State: "California", Value: "Value2",
  State: "Texas", Value: "Value3"
]
}
```

But your model would need to be updated to look something like this:

```
public class StateRequest : PublicRequest
{
    public string GeneralComment { get; set; }
    public List<StateWithValue> StatesWithValues { get; set; }
}
```

Note: There is a typo with general vs Global in your sample code